# VueJS always automatic append sharp sign(#/) to all pages at the end of URL

Tags: laravel, vue.js

After integrating VueJS into the website, I see that the website URL always ends of /#. How to remove it?

Example: change from

```
www.noti-solutions.com/#/
```

to

```
www.noti-solutions.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  `mode: 'history'` to the router, this will remove the `#` sign from the end of the urls.

Some thing like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

You can read more about this [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, add the below line in web.php

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AppController@index')->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```